# How do I create a New TextView Progmatically when a button is clicked?

Tags: java, android, textview

So I would like to create a new TextView when a button is clicked. For some reason, TextView(this) doesn't work when it is inside of an onClick(). I would like to be able to do this with just java.

Again, when I create a TextView inside of onClick, there is an error when I make a TextView(this).

```
EditText name = layout.findViewById(R.id.enterName);
        final String Name = name.getText().toString();
        Button create = layout.findViewById(R.id.create);
        create.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TextView textView = new TextView(this);
                textView.setText(Name);
            }
        });
```

I get the error, "TextView
(android.content.Context)
in TextView cannot be applied
to
(anonymous android.view.View.OnClickListener)".

Comment: Check my answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56499763/unable-to-display-textview-on-button-click-in-android/56500040#56500040

Answer (score 0):

`this` in the context of the inner class points to the instance of the inner class, which is not (as the error says) a `Context` (it's an event listener). If you want to use the outer class instance, you have to prefix the `this` with a class qualifier, i.e. `MyClass.this`, where `MyClass` is the name of the class you are calling this code from.

Answer (score 0):

When you are inside of the click listener `this` refers to the listener, not the activity. You need to instantiate the TextView with a reference to the activity or context instead.

Answer (score 0):

**Try to replace this line:**

```
  TextView textView = new TextView(this);
```

**With this line:**

```
TextView textView = new TextView(Activity.this);
```

You need to use your `Activity.this` if you want to pass the context.

`this` refers to the inner class (OnClickListener) and not to your Activity (your outer class)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is Ok, the only problem is that you are creating a textview but not adding it to the layout.

So add

```
layout.addView(textView);
```

below

```
textView.setText(Name);
```